# Show that $\operatorname{Gal}(K/L)$ is the intersection of all conjugacy classes of $\operatorname{Gal}(K/k)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Let $K/L$ be Galois extension and $F\subset k\subset L \subset K$ fields such that $L$ is the smallest subfield of $K$ such that $L/F$ is normal. Show that $\operatorname{Gal}(K/L)=\bigcap_{\sigma \in\operatorname{Gal}(K/F)} \sigma\operatorname{Gal}(K/k)\sigma^{-1}$.

I've been stuck on this problem for some time. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: show that $\sigma\operatorname{Gal}(K/k)\sigma^{-1}=\operatorname{Gal}(K/\sigma(k))$. Then use the normality of $L$ to think about where exactly $\sigma(k)$ lands.

Comment: could you elaborate? Thanks!

Comment: By smallness, $L$ is in fact the normal closure of $F$. The image of any subfield of $L$ is thus contained in...?